# Python 2.7 & GCP Google BigQuery: Capturing file load errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-bigquery

All,

I'm getting some Python 2.7 BiqQuery (BQ) data loads "operations ready" and I'm struggling with the right way to capture file loading errors in a comparable manner as other Big Data DW platforms I've used in the past.

In BQ, I can access the errors from this and examples are below:   bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri.errors

---

```
{
    {'reason': 'invalid', 
        'message': "Could not parse 'r2501' as int for field lineNum (position 0) starting at location 56708 ", 
        'location': 'gs://bucketNameHere/fake-data.csv'} 
    {'reason': 'invalid', 
        'message': 'CSV table references column position 2, but line starting at position:56731 contains only 2 columns.', 
        'location': 'gs://bucketNameHere/fake-data.csv'}
    {'reason': 'invalid', 
        'message': "Could not parse 'a' as int for field lineNum (position 0) starting at location 56734 ", 
        'location': 'gs://bucketNameHere/fake-data.csv'}
    {'reason': 'invalid', 
        'message': "Could not parse 'a' as int for field lineNum (position 0) starting at location 56739 ", 
        'location': 'gs://bucketNameHere/fake-data.csv'}
    {'reason': 'invalid', 
        'message': 'CSV table references column position 1, but line starting at position:56751 contains only 1 columns.', 
        'location': 'gs://bucketNameHere/fake-data.csv'}
}
```

---

This is good, but I really need a little bit better information, particularly the line number of the error, that is the main issue I'm having.

In Redshift:  stl_loaderror_detail & stl_load_errors   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html

In SnowflakeDB:  load_history & TABLE(VALIDATE(table_name, job_id => '_last'));   https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/validate.html

In summary, I need to load the data I can (set my max_bad_records fairly high), and when records fail, I need to know:

1. the filename of the load (in case I do a wildcard file load), this
   is currently provided
2. the line number where the error occurred, this is currently not provided, but the byte# is embedded in the message - "starting at location" or "position:".    I really need line number as a stand alone element
3. error message, this is provided and the current message is more than adequet

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks and best...Rich

p.s. I'll follow up with a comment containing my load script, I think the way I'm grabbing the statistics might be helpful for folks since it took me a while to figure out.

p.s.s. 
running on Linux and GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set
python 2.7

library versions as follows:

```
google-cloud==0.29.0 
google-cloud-bigquery==0.28.0
google-cloud-core==0.28.0




# load a table to bq from gcs with the schema
def load_table_from_gcs(dataset_name, table_name, schema, source, skip_leading_rows=1, source_format='CSV', max_bad_records=0, write_disposition='WRITE_EMPTY', project=None):
    try:

        # convert the schema json string to a list
        schemaList = convert_schema(schema)

        bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(project=project)
        dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_name)
        table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)
        table = bigquery.Table(table_ref, schema=schemaList)

        bigquery_client.create_table(table)

        job_id_prefix = "bqTools_load_job"
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
        job_config.create_disposition = 'NEVER'
        job_config.skip_leading_rows = skip_leading_rows
        job_config.source_format = source_format
        job_config.write_disposition = write_disposition

        if max_bad_records:
            job_config.max_bad_records = max_bad_records

        load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
            source, table_ref, job_config=job_config,
            job_id_prefix=job_id_prefix)

        # the following waits for table load to complete
        load_job.result()

        print("------ load_job\n")
        print("load_job: " + str(type(load_job)))
        print(dir(load_job))

        print("------ load_job.result\n")
        job_result = load_job.result
        print("job_result: " + str(type(job_result)))
        print(job_result)

        job_exception = load_job.exception
        job_id = load_job.job_id
        job_state = load_job.state
        error_result = load_job.error_result
        job_statistics = load_job._job_statistics()
        badRecords = job_statistics['badRecords']
        outputRows = job_statistics['outputRows']
        inputFiles = job_statistics['inputFiles']
        inputFileBytes = job_statistics['inputFileBytes']
        outputBytes = job_statistics['outputBytes']

        print("\n ***************************** ")
        print(" job_state:      " + str(job_state))
        print(" error_result:   " + str(error_result))
        print(" job_id:         " + str(job_id))
        print(" badRecords:     " + str(badRecords))
        print(" outputRows:     " + str(outputRows))
        print(" inputFiles:     " + str(inputFiles))
        print(" inputFileBytes: " + str(inputFileBytes))
        print(" outputBytes:    " + str(outputBytes))
        print(" type(job_exception):  " + str(type(job_exception)))
        print(" job_exception:  " + str(job_exception))
        print(" ***************************** ")

        print("------ load_job.errors \n")
        myErrors = load_job.errors
        # print("myErrors: " + str(type(myErrors)))
        for errorRecord in myErrors:
            print(errorRecord)

        print("------ ------ ------ ------\n")

        # TODO:  need to figure out how to get # records failed, and which ones they are
        # research shoed "statistics.load_job" - but not sure how that works

        returnMsg = 'load_table_from_gcs {}:{} {}'.format(dataset_name, table_name, source)

        return returnMsg

    except Exception as e:
        errorStr = 'ERROR (load_table_from_gcs): ' + str(e)
        print(errorStr)
        raise
```

Comment: edited topic to add my load code

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be possible as this is not API related but rather what BQ's backend returns as response (one possibility might be to start a [new issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) on BQ tracker and see what the team thinks of this)

Comment: Thanks Willian, I added a ticket (69405901) and will keep this thread posted should I get a response.

Answer (score 1):

The reason BigQuery doesn't report line number for errors is because the file is split and parsed by many workers in parallel. Say if a worker is responsible for offset 10000~20000 of the file, it'll seek to 10000 and start parsing from there. When it fails to parse a line, it only knows the start offset of the line. To know the line number it'll need to scan from the beginning of the file.

You can find out the line given the start offset. Is there a specific reason that you need the line number?

Comment: I need the original records and information back on why they failed.  Having this information will provide insight to the data providers on changes they should make to the data prior to sending to us, or for us to make changes in our load.  Pretty standard stuff, what failed and why?  If I can't get the line#, not a big deal, it's useful but not urgent.  The failed data and why are the most important.

Comment: BigQuery allows a single CSV line to be as big as 10MB. It'll be very inefficient to return a 10MB line inside an error message. Even worse to return it in 100 warnings. Instead an offset is returned so you can retrieve the failed line from the file. The why is already in the error message? "Could not parse 'r2501' as int for field lineNum (position 0)" as in your question?

Comment: From an operational perspective, I need to know which records failed (from which files) and why.  I'd like to also know the line number of the failed line, but this appears to be difficult (though others are doing it), please think of this from an operations perspective, you receive hundreds of files each night feeding different systems/tables, which files had errors, what were they (the message and the failed record).

Comment: Thanks for the links. Looks like Redshift returns a sample of the line, character(1024). We can probably do that too. I filed a feature request https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69640730. Since they don't require the JSON to be new-line delimitted, I would assume they process the file sequentially instead of in parallel, as it'll be very expensive to scan a 1TB file to find out the line number.